# Problema con la asignación de una variable

Tags: javascript, array, variables

Tengo el siguiente `Script` , donde espero que la variable `"backup"` tenga la información inicial de la variable `array`.
Sin embargo al remover un elemento de la variable `"array"`, también lo borra de la variable `"backup"`.

```js
var array = ["a","b"];
var backup = array;
  
array.splice("b",1);
console.log(array);
console.log(backup);
```

Yo esperaría que la variable `backup` no se alterará , ¿Alguien sabe como controlar esto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al hacer `var backup = array;` está asignando una referencia al mismo array en otra variable *(backup)*.En pocas palabras ambos están apuntando al mismo objeto. Es por eso que al cambiar el contenido de `array` , `backup` también será modificado.

Cuando se desea hacer un `backup` y sus datos son tipos primitivos como su caso, bastaría con usar [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/slice) que retornará una copia ***superficial*** del `array`.

**Código**

```js
var array = ["a","b"];
var backup = array.slice(0);
array.splice("b",1);
console.log(array);
console.log(backup);
```

El código anterior clona de la matriz original; tenga en cuenta que si existen objetos en su matriz, las referencias se mantienen; es decir, el código anterior no hace una copia "profunda" de los contenidos de la matriz.

```js
var array = ["a","b", {'nombre': 'Stack'}];
var backup = array.slice(0); 
//Modificamos el array Backup y se refleja en el principal
backup[2].nombre = 'Flow';
array.splice("b",1);
console.log(array);
console.log(backup);
```

Para este caso se puede recurrir al método [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify) para convertir el elemento en texto JSON , para luego con [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse)  convertir este String a un objeto.  *(Con la posibilidad de tener mejores métodos)*

```js
var array = ["a","b", {'nombre': 'Stack'}];
var backup = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( array ));
backup[2].nombre = 'Floww';
array.splice("b",1);
console.log(array);
console.log(backup);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu experiencia me has ayudado a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido al maravilloso mundo de JavaScript. En este caso entran en juego los conceptos de objeto, literal, variable y declaración.

`["a","b"]` es un literal de tipo array (en inglés "array literal")

El engine al ejecutar la declaración `var array = ["a","b"];` lo que hace es asignar el literal a una posición de memoria como un objeto y asigna una referencia de memoria a la variable array.

El agregar en la siguiente línea (enunciado / statement) `var backup = array;` lo que hace el engine es asignar la referencia de memoria asignada a array a backup.

En la siguiente línea `array.splice("b",1);` lo que ocurre es que se aplica la función splice al objeto referido por array el cual es el mismo que el objeto referido por backup.

Cuando el literal es conocido lo más sencillo sería escribir dos veces el literal, una vez por cada declaración.

```js
var array = ["a","b"];
var backup = ["a","b"];
  
array.splice("b",1);
console.log(array);
console.log(backup);
```

Cuando no se trata de literales sino de objetos habría que preguntarnos si nos interesa únicamente el valor o si nos interesan también otras propiedades del objeto que cuando se habla de realizar copias superficiales y profundas, pero esto ya sería de tema de otra pregunta.